# Visual Basic Selection Sort "Index out of range"

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

I've recently been trying to create a selection sort program in visual basic. I've managed to get it to sort integers in an array into descending order however, when I tried to use the same method to get it to sort the array into ascending order it will do it successfully but i will get an "index out of range" error. Below is my code:

```
Sub sortDescending()
    Dim array() As Integer = {3, 5, 200}
    Dim maxPos As Integer
    Dim firstI As Integer
    While firstI <= UBound(array)
        For i = firstI To UBound(array)
            If array(i) > array(maxPos) Then
                maxPos = i
            End If
        Next
        Dim largestNumber As Integer = array(maxPos)
        array(maxPos) = array(firstI)
        array(firstI) = largestNumber
        firstI = firstI + 1
        maxPos = firstI
        Console.WriteLine(largestNumber)
    End While
End Sub

Sub sortAscending()
    Dim array() As Integer = {3, 5, 200}
    Dim minpos As Integer
    Dim firstI As Integer
    While firstI >= LBound(array)
        For i = firstI To LBound(array)
            If array(i) < array(minpos) Then
                minpos = i
            End If
        Next
        Dim smallestNumber As Integer = array(minpos)
        array(minpos) = array(firstI)
        array(firstI) = smallestNumber
        firstI = firstI + 1
        minpos = firstI
        Console.WriteLine(smallestNumber)
    End While
```

As I said, the descending sort works with no problems however, the ascending one is giving me the error. Is anyone able to show me how to fix this? Thanks :)

Comment: You need to tell us on what line you get the error.  Also `data = data.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x).ToArray()` is all you need.  change `OrderByDescending` to `OrderBy` for ascending

Comment: Oh my bad, I get the error on "Dim smallestNumber As Integer = array(minpos). Unfortunately this program is for an assignment so it needs to be done using the selection sort method :/

Comment: `firstI >= LBound(array)` is always True so you'll never exit the loop...once it gets above 2, Index is out of range. Unless you're building your own sort routine for a specific reason, you should do as Plutonix suggested and use built in sorting capabilities.

Comment: Do you know of a way I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To apply selection sort if you do not use built in `order by` then you have to define the sorting algorithm correctly.

The issue you faced actually with while loop never ends so always examines to be true.I have converted that to for loop and corrected the swapping at the end.

Here is a function using your test case.

```
Private Sub SortArray(ByRef array() As Integer)

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim minimum As Integer
Dim swapValue As Integer
Dim upperBound As Integer
Dim lowerBound As Integer

lowerBound = LBound(array)
upperBound = UBound(array)

For i = lowerBound To upperBound

      minimum = i 
      For j = i + 1 To upperBound
           'Search for the smallest remaining item in the array
           If array(j) < array(minimum) Then
                'A smaller value has been found, remember the position in the array
                minimum = j
           End If
      Next j

      If minimum <> i Then
           'Swap array Values
           swapValue = array(minimum)
           array(minimum) = array(i)
           array(i) = swapValue
      End If

Next i
End Sub
```

call this function with the myArray.

```
Dim numbers = New Integer() {3, 5, 200}    
SortArray(numbers)
```

What the code does:

> 1.Find the smallest element in array.
>
> 2.Exchange the element in first pos and smallest found.so now smallest elemnet comes to first pos.
>
> 3.Repeat above two steps with the list having one less element.(smallest element discarded from further processed)

Final output

[image]